# Is it possible to reuse code in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to reuse code between different Jenkins deployments. Is it possible to share, for example, both to staging and to production, such that the only differences are the environment variables?

I imagine it could look something like this (although this obviously doesn't work):

```
pipeline {
    stage("Dev Deploy"){
        environment {
            PROP1 = "abc"
        }
        deploy ()
    }
    stage("Prod Deploy"){
        environment {
            PROP1 = "xyz"
        }
        deploy ()
    }
}

deploy = steps{
            sh "./gradlew deploy -Pproperty1=${env.PROP1}"
        }
```

Answer (score 16):

You are close. You can't quite do it in straight declarative, but if you mix in a little scripted you can accomplish this with a Closure. The "steps" has to be in each stage so you can run a "script", but the Closure defined as `deploy` can have any normal steps in it.

```
def deploy = {
            sh "./gradlew deploy -Pproperty1=${env.PROP1}"
        }

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Dev Deploy"){
            environment {
                 PROP1 = "abc"
            }
            steps {
                script {deploy ()}
            }
        }
        stage("Prod Deploy"){
            environment {
               PROP1 = "xyz"
            }
            steps {
                script {deploy ()}
            }
        }
    }
}
```